# Does the coefficient from regressing a binary variable on a binary outcome only show the effect of when that binary variable is true?

Tags: logistic, panel-data, binary-data, fixed-effects-model, clogit

I have a conditional fixed effects logistic regression of parental health shocks (0 if no shock, 1 if health shock) and clinically problematic child development (0 if no development problems in the child, 1 if development problems in the child).

I have 3 waves of panel longitudinal data. When I look at the coefficient on parental health shock I assume I am looking at an effect of health shock being true on the effect of problematic development being true.

I recently read a thread which made me wonder, although I consider the coefficient as a change from binary no health shock (0) to binary health shock (1) on a change from no binary developmental problem (0) to binary developmental problem (1), does the effect of a change in the opposite direction, from binary health shock (1) to binary no health shock (0), also enter into the coefficient or screw up my results in some other way?

**For example,** I assume that across the 3 waves parents with binary health shock values of 0,0,1 are included in the analysis but parents with health shock values 1,1,0 wouldn't contribute anything? Am I wrong? What does this imply for the coefficient of health shock on development I report, is is an effect of both health getting better and health getting worse? Or is it just the effect of a health decline on a developmental decline?